# How to update nested structure of a published variable using another api call

Tags: api, swiftui, combine

I have a published var called spotWallet in my BinanceStore class which conforms to observaleObject. I can create a publisher and subscribe to it. but there is property in my top level struct called balances which is an array of Balance struct. What I want to achieve is would like to update a property of Balance called price which comes from another network call. I cannot get that to work, in clean combine swiftui way.

```
class BinanceStore: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    @Published var spotWallet: SpotWallet?
    @Published var loadingError: String = ""
    @Published var showAlert: Bool = false
    private var cancellableSet: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
    private let binanceFetcher: BinanceFetchable
    
    init(binanceFetcher: BinanceFetchable) {
        self.binanceFetcher = binanceFetcher
    }
    
    func AccountDetailsOnSpot() async {
        binanceFetcher.getAccountDetailsOnSpot()
            .sink { (dataResponse) in
                if dataResponse.error != nil {
                    self.createAlert(with: dataResponse.error!)
                } else {
                    self.spotWallet = dataResponse.value!
                }
            }.store(in: &cancellableSet)
    }
    
    func createAlert( with error: NetworkError ) {
        loadingError = error.localizedDescription
        self.showAlert = true
    }
}

struct SpotWallet: Codable, Hashable {
    let makerCommission, takerCommission, buyerCommission, sellerCommission: Int
    let canTrade, canWithdraw, canDeposit: Bool
    let updateTime: Int
    let accountType: String
    let balances: [Balance]
    let permissions: [String]
}


protocol BinanceFetchable {
    func getAccountDetailsOnSpot() -> AnyPublisher<DataResponse<SpotWallet, NetworkError>, Never>
}

class BinanceFetcher {
    var coinPublisher = PassthroughSubject<CoinBalance, Never>()
}

extension BinanceFetcher: BinanceFetchable {
    
    func getAccountDetailsOnSpot() -> AnyPublisher<DataResponse<SpotWallet, NetworkError>, Never> {
        let endpoint = "/api/v3/account"
        let params = BinanceWrapper.shared.makeRequestReady(queries: nil)
        let url = URL(string: "\(BinanceWrapper.BINANCE_BASE_URL)\(endpoint)")!
        return AF.request(url, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: BinanceWrapper.BINANCE_HTTP_HEADERS)
            .validate()
            .publishDecodable(type: SpotWallet.self)
            .map { response in
                response.mapError { error in
                    return NetworkError.parsing(description: error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: You "would like to update a property of Balance called price".   You haven't shown what the "Balance" structure/class looks like.  Your "balances" field is a let constant - if Balance is also a structure then you're not going to be able to change it because that structure is part of "let" field.  Where are you having trouble?  What error are you working around?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).